# How to convert the date format in java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

```
String Resultmasterid=res1.getString(1);
System.out.println(Resultmasterid);
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHMM");

Date varDate1=dateFormat1.parse(Resultmasterid);
dateFormat1=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:MM");
String Final_admitDT=dateFormat1.format(varDate1);
```

This is my code I get the date as `yyyyMMddHHMM` format, now I need to change the format in `dd-mmm-yyyy HH:MM`. I get the result but it is not correct. Can any one help me on this please.

Comment: Why is it incorrect? what do you get? what do you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmm");    
SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm");
```

instead of

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHMM");
SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:MM");
```

[SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
MM indicates month
mm indicates minutes
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```
dateFormat1=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm");
```

because `mm` represent the *Minute in hour*, whereas `MM` represent *Month in year*.

Have a look at the docs of [SDF](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for more info on the patterns and pattern letters.

Answer (score 0):

Your patterns are wrong, you should use `MM` for month and `mm` for minutes:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmm");
...
dateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm");
```

By the way, you should also respect the Sun code conventions and not use local variables starting with a capital letters (e.g. `finalAdmitDT` instead of `Final_admitDT`).